# while installing composer file for Laravel it giving the below error

Tags: php, laravel

While I want to user Laravel 5 with PHP after installing XAMPP server I downloading composer from its website and while installing composer file in last step it is giving the error:

> The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

Comment: Try running `composer diagnose`

Comment: Check your anti-virus isn't blocking it and if you are on windows it may be failing due to SSL.